# Адекватное перемещение элемента и выделение текста

Tags: javascript

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/Ccx7r/) есть блок который можно перемещать, но он перемещается неадекватно, часто останавливается, постоянно хочет выделить текст и при этом изменяется курсор.

Я пытался бороться с выделением текста но

```
document.ondragstart = function() { return false }
document.body.onselectstart = function() { return false }
```

не помогает.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select):

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Кто бы еще подсказал как лаги устранить

Comment: Размести пример на jsfiddle.net и тогда уже можно будет понять, где лаги и как их исправить.

Comment: Разместил на jsfiddle.net